# 0xC03A001B error while trying to compact VHD

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, vhd, diskpart

What can be the reason of such error? I tried to compact both via DISKPART and `Optimize-Vhd` commandlet.

Via DISKPART I get following error:

```
DISKPART> compact vdisk

DiskPart has encountered an error: The requested operation cannot be performed on a virtual disk of this type.
See the System Event Log for more information.
```

Via Hyper-V commandlet I get such exception:

```
 Optimize-Vhd : Failed to compact the virtual disk.
 The system failed to compact 'd:\boot.vhd'.
 Failed to compact the virtual disk.
 The system failed to compact 'd:\boot.vhd': The requested operation cannot be performed on a virtual disk of this
 type. (0xC03A001B).
 At line:1 char:1
 + Optimize-Vhd -path D:\boot.vhd -Mode Full
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Optimize-VHD], VirtualizationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.Vhd.PowerShell.Cmdlets.OptimizeVhd
```

I reviewed similar questions here (e.g. [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/358610/what-are-the-possible-reasons-why-hyper-v-cant-compact-a-vhd)) and they are not relevant to me. My VHD is **not** the VM (it wasn't created by Hyper-V), and I have **no** *file system limitation* error.

VHD can be perfectly attached in Disk Management applet, which is weird, 'cause this applet should use the same APIs as PS cmdlets or DISKPART.

P.S. I run Win10 x64 Pro, DiskPart version 10.0.16299.15 and PS version

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  64
```

Comment: `My VHD is not the VM (it wasn't created by Hyper-V), and I have no file system limitation error.` - I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify this statement?

Comment: The `DISKPART` error says `See the System Event Log for more information.`.  If you check Event Viewer, what do you find?

Comment: @joeqwerty, this just mean that I have another error (as stated above) and therefore those question is not related to my problem. By `My VHD is not the VM` I mean that this VHD is not a virtual Hyper-V machine, but a dump of SD-Card, created by third-party app.

Comment: Moreover, the VHD is perfectly opened/attached by Disk Management applet, which is weird, 'cause it should use the same APIs as PS cmdlets or diskpart.

Comment: @BenScott, nothing new. Here are the screens from Event Viewer relevant to cmdlet: [1](https://imgur.com/Qbh79Ar), [2](https://imgur.com/scmbjBk). Also I tried to search eventwvr for diskpart events (e.g. by userpnp source) but found nothing relevant. Maybe you suggest another search strategy?

Comment: @Suncatcher - I can offer this much: 0xC03A001B is ERROR_SECTOR_NOT_FOUND.  I was assuming that had to be bogus, since it is a VHD.  But now you mention the VHD was created by a third-party tool.  That makes me suspect a bug in that third-party tool.  I would suggest contacting the provider of said third-party tool.

Comment: but why `VHD is perfectly opened/attached by Disk Management applet` as I stated before? Doesn't it use the same API as diskpart or PS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the 3rd party tool you're using creates *dynamically expanding* VHDs?  According to [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708394(v=ws.10).aspx), compact operation is only supported on dynamically expanding VHDs.

Comment: There is little to zero info in this tool about VHD it creates. Is there any way to check if my VHD is dynamically expanding?